# align image on right of bootstrap list-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need the image to fill top to bottom on right side of list-group. I have several css overrides in my style section, and can't seem to figure out what I'm missing? not sure if giving a fixed height width is the way to go or how to have it fill the set list height.

attached image shows the current alignment which seems to be below the label?

some list will already drop to line below.

[image]

```
    <style> 

.checkbox label:after, 
.radio label:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr,
.radio .cr {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon,
.radio .cr .cr-icon {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
    margin-left: 0.04em;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"],
.radio label input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"] + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon {
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .cr,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:disabled + .cr {
    opacity: .5;
}

.bv-bg-lightpink {
    background-color: lightpink;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-bg-lightblue {
    background-color: lightblue;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-bg-lightyellow {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-bg-lightgreen {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-bg-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-bg-red {
    background-color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.bv-not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

.MyDrugPix img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float:right
}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#acet" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label style="font-size: 1.5em">
             ACETAMINOPHEN
            </label>
            <div class="MyDrugPix" style="padding-right: 0px;"><img src="/images/IMG_0741.JPG" alt="DRUGS" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution for your problem.

Basically I set the div with the class `checkbox` as `width:100%`.

Then I make the div of the image, as `display:inline-block` so that it does not take up the whole width. Then set it to the right using the property `float:right;`, but this will cause the parent to not detect the elements height, to solve this I have added a clearfix. Refer [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for more about clearfix.

**CSS:**

```
.MyDrugPix {
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Clearfix:**

```
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```css
.checkbox label:after,
.radio label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr,
.radio .cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon,
.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  margin-left: 0.04em;
}


/*My changes*/

.MyDrugPix {
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 100%;
}

/*Clearfix for floating elements*/

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE7 */
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#acet" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
  <div class="checkbox clearfix">
    <label style="font-size: 1.5em">
             ACETAMINOPHEN
            </label>
    <div class="MyDrugPix"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="DRUGS" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

here is a CSS3 solution if you are open to it.

Using flex properties we can do the same by setting 3 properties alone!

**CSS3**

```
.checkbox {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.checkbox label:after,
.radio label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr,
.radio .cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon,
.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  margin-left: 0.04em;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#acet" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" style="background-color: lightyellow;">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label style="font-size: 1.5em">
             ACETAMINOPHEN
            </label>
    <div class="MyDrugPix" style="padding-right: 0px;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="DRUGS" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: ok let m try this, just to clarify, what is changed in my current style section aside from the .checkbox? anything other than adding the 3 lines?

Comment: @BarclayVision Which version do you want to implement? the CSS3 one? for the CSS3 one the checkbox class alone needs to be added!

Comment: got it, works great - thanks so much, I just couldn't figure out the alignment. On lines with wrapping text, the image is much smaller.

Comment: @BarclayVision can you share a fiddle with the issue and what you need, will try to help if possible!

Comment: thanks - i won't get to the fiddle today, will post later, Thanks for the main fix

Comment: here is https://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/a3m7dh4y/ when the line wraps the image becomes smaller, more lines... smaller image - also trying to make image an href but using anchor tag changes css formatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155444/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-barclayvision).